# Save List changes with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have an Object named Token. it has id, name, and value. After saving some data to db, I have loaded them into a web page

```
_____________________________________________
|____name____|____value____|____operation____|
   tkn1          10               ×
   tkn2          20               ×
```

the `×` sign enable me to delete a token from server collection
now. I have added token tkn3 with value 30 and deleted `tkn2` so
the table would be:

```
_____________________________________________
|____name____|____value____|____operation____|
   tkn1          10               ×
   tkn3          30               ×
```

With these changes to the collection, how can I reflect them into database
how to determine the records that deleted, and the records that added?

I applied tow solutions:

1. I have compared -in business logic layer- the old data with the new data
   and find the differences between the then send to database two lists, the first contains
   the added tokens and the second contains the ids of tokens to be deleted.
2. I added a flag named status to the object.. when I add the flag is NEW
   when I delete I just set flag to DELETE, and in DB layer I iterate over the collection
   one by one object and check the flag.. if NEW then add the record, if DELETE , delete it
   and if SAVED (no changes) I do no changes to it..

My questions:

- Is this way is good to do this task..?
- Is there a Pattern to accomplish this task?
- Can Hibernate help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

• Is this way is good to do this task..?
NO

• Is there a Pattern to accomplish this task?
YES

• Can Hibernate help me to do that?
Hibernate provides the solution for such situation using Cascade Attribute for List property

Refer
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Answer (score 0):

The blow entity should solve your problem.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

private static enum Status {
    NEW,
    PERSISTENT,
    REMOVED
}

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;
private int value;

@Transient
private Status uiStatus = Status.NEW;

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public Status getUiStatus() {
    return this.uiStatus;
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

@PostLoad
public void onLoad() {
    this.uiStatus = Status.PERSISTENT;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setUiStatus(Status uiStatus) {
    this.uiStatus = uiStatus;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```